# Using C++ with Objective-C, How can I fix "Conflicting declaration 'typedef int BOOL'"?

Tags: c++, objective-c, declaration, typedef, objective-c++

I have a lot of code in C++, originally built on a PC. I'm trying to make it work with Objective-C on a Mac.  To that end, I created an Objective-C framework to house the C++ code and added a thin wrapper.  But I'm running into a typedef problem in my C++ code.

When I was working with C++ on a PC I used the `BOOL` variable defined in WinDef.h.   So when I moved everything over the Mac I added in `typedef int BOOL;` to make sure the `BOOL` variable would still compile as expected.

But when I try to compile I get an error: "`Conflicting declaration 'typedef int BOOL'`".  I assume this is because `BOOL` is a keyword in Objective-C, and so is already defined. I also can't just use the Objective-C `BOOL` since it is an unsigned char and not an int.

While I was looking for possible solutions I found [one](http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2005/Feb/msg00010.html) that mentions *undefining BOOL*, but I couldn't find how to do that (nor do I know if it actually works).  [Another](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/719522?start=0&tstart=0) suggests *renaming BOOL* in the C++ files to something that isn't a keyword.  This suggestion  isn't an option for me because other projects rely on the C++ code.  Ideally, any changes I make should stay in one file or at least should not negatively impact the code on a Windows machine.

How can I undefine the Objective-C definition of BOOL for my C++ files and use the C++ definition I added?  Is there a better way to deal with this problem?

In case it helps I'm using: Xcode 3.2.5, 64-bit and Mac OS X 10.6.6

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: Why did you use `BOOL` in the first place? C++ already has a `bool` type.

Comment: Because on Windows, many APIs use the BOOL type, defined by Windows, which is indeed an int. It is not compatible with BOOL, especially not if it is part of a struct that must be passed to such an API (On Windows, bool is byte-sized and BOOL is four bytes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a little confused by some of the discussion, but instead of `typedef int BOOL;` how about just:

```
#ifndef BOOL
  #define BOOL int
#endif
```

If you're using `typedef` then `#undef` won't work since they are two different things. `#define`/`#undef` operate on preprocessor symbols that perform replacements, whereas a typedef is part of the language that creates an alias of another type.

A preprocessor symbol can be undefined at any point because it is simply an instruction to the preprocessor that tells it to no longer use that definition when performing replacements.  However, a `typedef` can't be undefined, as it is something that gets created within a particular scope, rather than the linear processing that occurs using the preprocessor. (In the same way, you wouldn't expect to be able to declare a global variable `int x;` and then at some point in your code be able to say 'stop recognizing x as a variable.')

The reason I suggest the #define in my answer is that it's possible that the ObjectiveC `#define` is being hit only while compiling some of your code. That could be an explanation as to why you may get errors in your C++ when you removed the `typedef`, but still get a conflict if it is in.  But, so, if the assumptions are correct, once you check for the definition prior to trying to define it, you should be able to avoid the conflicting definitions when they occur.

As a final note: in this particular situation, you could also just put your `typedef` inside the check instead of a `#define`.  However, I gravitated toward doing it the way I did both because it's a very common idiom, and because that block will also prevent you from defining it twice in your C++ code if it ends up included twice.  Probably neither very compelling reasons if you very much prefer the `typedef` and know it's not an issue in the code. :)

Comment: :) oops, well I posted after your problem was already solved, glad you got it working!

Comment: I tried both ways you mentioned (the `#ifdef` with `#define BOOL int` and `typedef int BOOL;` inside).  The first way worked just fine, but the second generated the same `Conflicting declaration` error (I completely don't understand how that's possible, just repeating what Xcode told me!).  Thanks for the alternate solution!

Comment: huh, that's very odd. ahh well, probably one of those things where it's best not to think too hard about it. :D and thanks for the note! ♡

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't know anything about (Objective-|)C(|++) types.  Think of the preprocessor as an arbitrary templating language that knows nothing about the language it's rendering.  See http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-371.1/runtime/objc.h for more.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `BOOL` is a `#define` in Objective-C too. You will have problems with your conflicting `BOOL` define, even if you manage to

```
#undef BOOL
```

because your type and its type do not necessarily match in size and "signedness". Must your `BOOL` really be an `int`, instead of whatever it is that Obj-C defines it as? In other words, can't you omit your `#define` and simply use the Obj-C one?

Comment: If I comment out my `typedef int BOOL` in my C++ file I get errors all throughout the rest of my C++ files any time `BOOL` is used.  So I don't think I can use the Obj-C BOOL definition instead.

Comment: How can that be? I hope it is only defined once. Just remove that and include "objc.h" instead. FWIW, what kind of errors?

Comment: Oh, I think that worked!  At least it compiles error free now.  I did what you said and add in `#include <objc/objc.h>` so hopefully things will be smother from here.  Thank you!  FWIW they were mostly errors like `'BOOL' does not name a type` and `ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'BOOL' with no type`.

Answer (score 0):

If you could go back in time, I would say "Don't use `typedef int BOOL` in your own code".

Now that you've actually done it, though, you are in a bit of a pickle. Generally, you should avoid using external data types for your own code except to interface with external code. Standard types are fine, assuming that you can guarantee compiling with a standard compliant compiler on every platform you target.

The most forward looking solution is to stop using `BOOL` as a type in your platform agnostic code. In the meantime, you can use all sorts of preprocessor hackery to make your use of `BOOL` compile, but you might hit some strange link errors if you don't use `BOOL` in the same way (via #includes) everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I use cmake to load the freeimage library and i'm using kubuntu 14.x 
I had this problem with

```
"error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef CARD8 BOOL’"
```

and I thought it would be good to share my solution with people that have this problem!

install FreeImage on Linux:

```
sudo apt-get install libfreeimage-dev
```

In my CMakeLists.txt file I have:

```
set(FREEIMAGE_LIBRARY_AND_HEADER_DIRRECTORY /usr/libs)
find_path(FREEIMAGE_LIBRARY_AND_HEADER_DIRRECTORY, FreeImage.h)
find_library(FREEIMAGE_LIBRARY_AND_HEADER_DIRRECTORY, freeimage)
include_directories(${FREEIMAGE_LIBRARY_AND_HEADER_DIRRECTORY})
target_link_libraries(freeimage)
```

And in my main.cpp I have:

```
#include <FreeImage.h>
#ifndef CARD8
#define BYTE CARD8
#define BOOL CARD8
#endif
```

And some extra code to capture OpenGl frame on disk:

```
void generateImage(){
  int w, h; // get the width and height of the OpenGL window!
  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
  GLubyte * pixels = new GLubyte[3*w*h];
  glReadPixels(0,0,w,h,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

  FIBITMAP * image = FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBits(pixels,w,h,3 * w, 24, 0x0000FF, 0xFF0000, 0x00FF00, false);
  FreeImage_Save(FIF_BMP,image, "../img/text.bmp",0);

  //Free resource
  FreeImage_Unload(image);
  delete[] pixels;
}
```

I hope this helps the ones who have problem with this!

Regards 
Kahin